# package install error related to conda

Tags: docker, miniconda

How do I install the following 2 packages using miniconda?

```
pip install PyICU

pip install pycld2
```

I got an error related to gcc therefore I run

```
conda install gcc
```

Now I am getting error related to **g++**

I am not looking for a solution that involve creating separate environment. I am using docker image of miniconda and will like to build a new image from miniconda.

Comment: Please post the exact error messages, and maybe the Dockerfile too... without that, how can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved after installing essential packages using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile for installing g++ in Miniconda Docker image along with all other dependencies.

```
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y install curl bzip2 \
    libblas-dev \
    g++\
    build-essential \
    && curl -sSL https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && bash /tmp/miniconda.sh -bfp /usr/local \
    && rm -rf /tmp/miniconda.sh \
    && conda install -y python=3 \
    && conda update conda \
    && apt-get -qq -y remove curl bzip2 \
    && apt-get -qq -y autoremove \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/log/dpkg.log \
    && conda clean --all --yes
```